# Pl/SQL assign the string to a variable and print the value each time

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

Create a function named 'display_player_skill' which accepts an input parameter. The input parameter is 'player_id' with number as its data type.This function should return the skil_id for the given 'player_id'.

I had tried

```
create or replace function display_player_skill (player_id in number)
    return varchar2
is
    skill_name varchar2(100);
begin
    select s.name into skill_name from k_skill s 
    inner join k_player p on p.skill_id=s.id
    where p.skill_id= player_id;

    case skill_name
        when 'Raider' then return 'Player is a Raider';
        when 'All rounder' then return 'Player is a All Rounder';
    end case;

exception
    when case_not_found then return 'Player is a Defender';
    when no_data_found then return 'No Such Player';
end;
/
```

but I had to return the skill_id for the given player_id and display skill_name. By assign the string to a variable and print the value each time.

Comment: where you are calling this function, In a SQL statement or PL/SQL block?

Comment: The assignment statement you showed doesn't say anything about displaying the name?

Comment: Surely that should be `'Player is an All Rounder'`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems where clause is not correct (it's quite strange to compare skill_id with player_id).

```
where p.skill_id= player_id;
```

Besides, if you have column player_id in k_player, Oracle will treat player_id as column name. So you need to name your parameter something like p_player_id (p_ for parameter)

So I'd expect your code looks something like:

```
create or replace function display_player_skill (p_player_id in number)
    return varchar2
    is
    skill_name varchar2(100);
    skill_id   number;
    BEGIN
    select s.name, s.id into skill_name, skill_id from k_skill s 
    inner join k_player p on p.skill_id=s.id
    where p.player_id= p_player_id;

    dbms_output.put_line('Skill name is a '||skill_name);

    return skill_id;

EXCEPTION
when no_data_found then return 'No Such Player';
END;
/
```

I don't know your tables structure so some column names may require correction.

Comment: You've got a typo, an extra "into" instead of a comma in the select.

Answer (score 0):

try it:

```
 select s.name, s.id into skill_name,skill_id from k_skill s 
        inner join k_player p on p.skill_id=s.id
        where p.player_id= p_player_id;

  --      dbms_output.put_line('Skill name is a '||skill_name);

        return skill_id;
```